# Colloquialisms in Math Terminology

Tags: soft-question, terminology, math-history

What are some of your favorite colloquial sounding names for mathematical objects, proofs, and so on?  For example, manifolds are often described using an *atlas* and a *neighborhood* describes a small set surrounding a point.

Answer (score 5):

I especially like the agricultural theme very consistently upheld in sheaf theory (stalks, germs, ...).

Comment: That's a great example!

Answer (score 4):

There's the arboreal theme in graph theory (forests, trees, leaves, roots, ...).

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe no one has yet mentioned the following. These were quite common, at least at one time (1970s).

**abstract nonsense** -- refers to (Eilenberg/MacLane) category theory

**invariant under change of notation** -- refers to differential geometry, especially when tensors are involved

**proof by diagram chasing** -- refers to a proof involving commutative diagrams, especially when the proof is essentially solving a path puzzle or hedge maze puzzle